# Mongo take advantage of indexing when doing $elemMatch with regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, indexing

I have a model pretty much like this:

Document Release

- has an embedded array ReleaseDetails[]
- The ReleaseDetails array contains documents of type ReleaseDetails
- A ReleaseDetails document has a field called ArtistName of type text
- A ReleaseDetails document has a field called Type of type text

I basically want to do this:

retrieve all the Release documents that have an entry in their ReleaseDetails array which (both) has ArtistName=someRegexExpression AND Type=someOtherRegexExpression. Basically I do this:

```
db.getCollection("releasesCollection").
          find({ "ReleaseDetails" : 
                 { "$elemMatch" : 
                      { "ArtistName" : {$regex:"^David"},
                        "Type" : {$regex:".*singer.*"}}})
```

Problem is, if I call explain() on such a query I can see that the indexes I've made on

`ReleaseDetails.ArtistName` and `ReleaseDetails.Type` are effectively not taken into account (the query just goes through all documents in the collection).

On the other hand, if I do the exact same query but replace the regex expressions with actual values, in other words, if I do this:

```
db.getCollection("releasesCollection").
          find({ "ReleaseDetails" : 
                 { "$elemMatch" : 
                      { "ArtistName" : "David Halliday",
                        "Type" : "mainSinger"}}})
```

in this case the indexs ARE taken into account (explain() show that clearly).

My question is then, is there a way to have a query that does $elemMatch WITH regex take advantage of the indexes?

(I'm asking because I've also seen that in fact, if you do a regex query on a basic field (like a text field, not an embedded-array field) AND that field is indexed, my regex query will infact take advantage of the indexes. Why is it that regex query on a basic indexed fields uses the index but regex query on an embedded-array indexed field fails to use the indexes?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two important things you may missed:

1.Only case sensitive prefix regexp can use index in mongodb, all others - can't.

For example following query will use index:

`db.users.find({ "name": /^andrew/ })`

2.Any query can use only one index per query, therefore it will be better to create compound index for your query:

```
db.items.ensureIndex({"ReleaseDetails.ArtistName": 1, "ReleaseDetails.Type" : 1});
```

And to take advantages of mongodb indexes you should not use *`like`* regexp -> `"Type" : {$regex:".*singer.*"}` (probably because of this regexp your query not use index).

If you really need *`like`* search that you can tokenize yourself `Type` and store it as an array. For example:

If you have following Type: *"My favorite singer"* you can:

1. Split this phrase into words and store in lower case: `[my, favorite, singer]`
2. Tokenize words that's bigger then 3 chars to use *`like`* search like this:
   `[my, fav, favo, favor, favori, favorit, favorite, avorite, vorite, orite, rite, ite, 
   avorit, vori]` (i've skipped singer word tokenizing)
3. After such tokenizing done you can search by exact match and your query will use index, but your database for sure will be bigger ;).

About algorithms how to tokenize words you can read from full text search engines like [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Comment: Yep, you're right. I was missinterpreting the data returned by explain() (more to the point the nscanned and nscannedobjects values).

Comment: Note that MongoDB supports full text search as of version 2.4 - you might find it suitable for your case.